# Sinon stub failed when upgrade ts-node to v10

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon, ts-node

Everything is ok when my ts-node version is 8.x ~ 9.x , but sinon stub failed when I upgraded ts-node to 10.x

The code likes below:

```
// file: ./lambda.ts
export const getAWSLambda = () => new AWS.Lambda({ region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION });
export class AWSLambda {
  private readonly lambda: AWS.Lambda;
  constructor() {
    this.lambda = getAWSLambda();
  }
  async invoke(params: ServerlessParams): Promise<ServerlessResponse> {
      const response = await this.lambda.invoke({
        // ...
      }).promise();
      return {};
  }
}


// file: unit.test.ts
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as lambda from './lambda';

describe('Lambda Unit Test', () => {
  let lambdaService: lambda.AWSLambda;
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
  let getAWSLambdaStub: sinon.SinonStub;
  let invokeStub: sinon.SinonStub;

  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    invokeStub = sandbox.stub();
    getAWSLambdaStub = sandbox.stub(lambda, 'getAWSLambda');
    getAWSLambdaStub.returns({
      invoke: () => ({
        promise: invokeStub,
      }),
    });
    lambdaService = new lambda.AWSLambda();
  });

  it('shound succeed to invoke', async () => {
    invokeStub.resolves({
      StatusCode: 200,
    });

    // -----------
    // called real function, stub failed.
    const res = await lambdaService.invoke();  

    expect(getAWSLambdaStub).to.be.calledOnce;
    expect(invokeStub).to.be.calledOnce;
  });
});
```

The stub failed, the real function was called.

- sinon: 11.1.2
- ts-node: 10.2.1
- typescript: 3.9.7
- node: 14.17.3

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "dist/src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "transpiler": "ts-node/transpilers/swc-experimental"
  }
}
```

Everything is ok when my ts-node version is 8.x ~ 9.x , but sinon stub failed when ts-node is v10. Is there any change in the import of module for ts-node's swc ?

> Add swc integration and new --transpiler option to use third-party transpilers for a massive speed boost on large codebases

I guess here is the cause of the problem, and I want to use ts-node v10, but I don't known how to fix the problems.

Comment: What is your test runner? ```mocha```? ```ts-mocha```?

Comment: @andreyunugro mocha